# ASP.NET MVC validation message encoding issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, encoding, asp.net-mvc-5

I have model with validation by data annotations:

```
public class MyModel 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название")] //cyrillic (cap)
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I see this validation message in browser, it looks like that:

```
Îòïðàâë ïîâòîðíî
```

I have `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in head.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your Razor templates (.cshtml/.vbhtml) files are UTF-8 encoded: in Visual Studio open your _Layout.cshtml and select File -> Save As and then Save with Encoding...

[image]

Then select Unicode (UTF-8 with signature):

[image]

Do the same for all your Razor templates and views.

Also if you are using HTML 5 you might use the shorter version of the meta tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: See my own answer. Actually everything from Razor views was OK. Problem was in the messages from dll's. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Andrei, I had the same problem. But your solution didn't work for me. I managed it only by saving cs-file in `UTF-8`. In earlier version of VS I had no problem with ErrorMessages in russian language.

Answer (score -1):

Accidently I found how to fix it:

```
Project properties -> Application -> Assembly Information -> Neutral language
```

[image]